# codeigniter session swapping on multiple request at the same time

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am having an ecommerce website running in codeigniter. The sessions are working fine on normal case. The problem starts when, say for example if two users are there on my website and assume that they are logged in, and when they click any action like add to cart or proceed to checkout or place the order the same time the login sessions are swapped.

Could anyone please help me on this! I have searched a lot on this but couldn't find a good solution.

I am using the config file like this

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = TRUE;
$config['sess_save_path'] = sys_get_temp_dir();
$config['sess_match_ip'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

I won;t be able to use the sess_driver as database since it will affect my website performance i believe.

Thanks in advance!.

Comment: Are these "Two" users connecting from different computers with different IP's etc or are you pretending to be "Two" users in the same browser?

Comment: Yes.. the "Two" users connecting from different computers with different IP's.. basically this is happening when the "Two" users request hit the server at the same time..

Comment: Show code where session is set.

Comment: The session is initialized in the autoload like this

`$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session');`

And the values are assigned like 

 `$sess_data = array(
                            'user_name' => 'test name'
                            ,'user_email' => 'test@test.com'
                          );
           $this->session->set_userdata($sess_data);`

Comment: Is it because of the PHP version.. ?? i am using version 5.6

Comment: @Feroz is it fixed ? if so, please share the answer here

Answer (score 0):

As you are saying that users have logged in, which means there is a 'Log In' button through which users are logging in your system. So the controller where your login function has been mentioned, you can create a constructor and load your session library there, like below :

```
public function __construct()
{ 
  $this->load->library('session'); 
}
```

And make sure there is 'Logout' button too in your system, where the sessions can be destroyed on click of 'Logout' button.
You can just give this a try. Just thought this might help.